# How to run a dynamic lib as root on Linux - to use systemd sdbus client interface?

Tags: linux, root, systemd

(Relatively new to Linux)

I have a C++ appilcation which is loading different components or plugins as dynamic libraries at runtime. This application is running at user-privilege and so does the libraries that it is loading also running fine as user-privileges.

Until, for a new component I had to write using client `sdbus` interface (`org.freedesktop.timedatectl1`) which needs to run as a root user. My problem is that, my application doesn't have a root privilege and thus whenever I making my library run, it fails with exception.

Can anyone help me understand how can I load my library in root-privilege, while the main application remains in user-privilege? Or if there is a fundamental problem with this approach, can you suggest me a work around.

Comment: Privileges apply at the process level, not to specific libraries.

Comment: You could implement the privileged operation in a separate program with setuid permission and execute this program from your main application (via your library).

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your response. I am wondering if there is a way I can give the required access to my user-privilege and move forward with this. Is there a way to grant access by scripts?

Comment: @Bodo Is there a way to grant the required access to the `user` account.

Comment: The application needs to be setuid root. It can give up its extra privileges during most of the program, but regain them before calling the library functions that need it.

Comment: It uses the `setreuid()` function to change its effective userid dynamically.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the sdbus API and its permissions concept. I suggest to show in form of a [mre] what API calls you want to use. Maybe someone knows if this requires root or if a permission can be granted to the user. (I read about polkit/PolicyKit, but I don't know any details.)